# Animated transition between two imageview

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation, android-imageview

**On one hand I have a layout with two ImageView :**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_cross2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_size"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_cross1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_size"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**On the other hand i have a list of image ressources :**

```
static int                      mImages[]               = new int[] {
        R.drawable.artistes,
        R.drawable.couple1,
        R.drawable.couple2,
        R.drawable.couple3,
        R.drawable.enfant,
        R.drawable.manege,
        R.drawable.manege2,
        R.drawable.metropolitain,
        R.drawable.panoramique,
        R.drawable.sacrecoeur               };
```

i have also a Scheduler made from Handler + postDelayed() to display the images one after another with a timer. This is working fine

my issue is about the transition animation from one imageview to the other, knowing that **i have to clean the imageviews each time to avoid OutOfMemoryExceptions :**

For now i do that in the schduled callback method :

```
if (mIndex == mImages.length) {
                    mIndex = 0; // repeat
                }
                if (mIndex % 2 != 0) { // pair
                    mImageCross2.setImageResource(mImages[mIndex++]);
                    Utils.crossfade(mImageCross2, mImageCross1, 1000/*duration*/);
                    mImageCross1.setImageResource(0);
                } else {
                    mImageCross1.setImageResource(mImages[mIndex++]);
                    Utils.crossfade(mImageCross1, mImageCross2, 1000);
                    mImageCross2.setImageResource(0);
                }
```

with this animation :

```
public static void crossfade(final ImageView viewIn, final ImageView viewOut, int duration) {
        Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        fadeIn.setDuration(duration);
        Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        fadeOut.setDuration(duration);
        fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                viewOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        fadeIn.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                viewIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        viewOut.startAnimation(fadeOut);
        viewIn.startAnimation(fadeIn);
    }
```

The animation is not great, the fade is not really smooth, what can i do to make it more smooth while having to clean the ImageView each times ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

My first suggestion is to simplify most of your code. Android has this nice little class called [`TransitionDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html)

so you can have just 1 image view and use the TransitionDrawable:

```
TransitionDrawable td = new TransitionDrawable( new Drawable[] {
    getResources().getDrawables(mImages[x]),
    getResources().getDrawables(mImages[y])
});
imageView.setImageDrawable(td);
```

and call the animation on `td` with

```
td.startTransition(1000);
 // and
td.reverseTransition(1000);
```

and keep using the `postDelayed` to trigger them

Comment: oh, by the way... I typed all that by heart, there might be a couple of typos around, once you type it on the IDE you'll see

Comment: i get a nullpointer exception at "getResources().getDrawables(mImages[0])" even using directly the resources numbers getResources().getDrawables(R.drawable.artistes), do you have any idea ?

Comment: put a breakpoint on that line and on the Debug window of your IDE you check `getResources()` does it return null? then check `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.artiste)` does it return null?

Comment: ok solved it was because i used "getRessource()" too soon i guess. Now i get the well known OutOfMemoryException ^^"

Comment: OOM is a different monster. You can try to see if `Picasso` library help you out. Or at some point you just need to use smaller images, or change it to a `VideoView`

Comment: well this is too much for what i'm using it for. i got back with my method and just reset the ImageViews in onAnimationEnd. But your solution is good so =)

Comment: change `getDrawables` to `getDrawable` I think